# "SendID" property breaks retrieval of UnsubEvent

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

[The documentation on UnsubEvents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubevent.htm) states I should be able to add a "SendID" property to learn from which send a user unsubscribed. 
However, when I use the SendID in the filter, I receive the below error:

> Error: The Filter Property 'SendID' is not a retrievable property.

Here is my code:

```
RetrieveRequest rrUnsub = new RetrieveRequest();

 rrUnsub.ObjectType = "UnsubEvent";

 rrUnsub.Properties = new[] { "PartnerKey", "EventDate" };

 SimpleFilterPart filterUnsub = new SimpleFilterPart();

 filterUnsub.Property = "SendID";

 filterUnsub.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;

 filterUnsub.Value = new string[] { "xxxxxxxx" };

 rrUnsub.Filter = filterUnsub;

  APIObject[] results = null;
  String requestId = null;

  String response = client.Retrieve(rrUnsub, out requestId, out results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else should be going on behind the scenes here. You're correct in SendID being retrievable. If you run a describe API call against the object type "UnsubEvent", SendID returns as retrievable:

```
Name|DataType|IsRetrievable|IsUpdatable|IsRequired
SendID|Int32|true|true|true
```

Also, when I directly test this call using a SOAP envelope, I have no problems:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-274403118" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>UnsubEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <Property>SendID</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>#####</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this case, I successfully retrieved records.

If this is all of your code, I'd say something is possibly wrong with the SDK. All the SDK *should* be doing is giving you a means to create what I hand-cranked out above, the actual xml/SOAP Envelope.

If this isn't all of the code, I can't truly speak to what's going on. I'd be inclined to think there's more going on here than I can see, but I'm not sure. In any case, SendID is not the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried running the above soap envelope and gave me this error in the response:   <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) SendID do not match with the fields of UnsubEvent retrieve</OverallStatus>.  Also, this is all the code I'm using to retrieve UnsubEvent.